# preg_replace question

Tags: php, preg-replace

I'm trying to use preg_replace to strip out a section of code but I am having problems getting it to work right.

Code Example:

```
$str = '<p class="code">some string here</p>';
```

PHP I'm using:

```
$pattern = array();
$pattern[0] = '!<p class="code">!';
$pattern[1] = '!</p>!';
preg_replace($pattern,"", $str);
```

This strips out the code just as I want with the exception of the space between the p and class.

Returns:

```
  some string here //notice the single space at the beginning.
```

I'm trying to get:

```
some string here //no space at the beginning.
```

I have been beating my head against the wall trying to find a solution. The reason I'm trying to strip it out in a chunk instead of breaking the preg_replace into pieces is because I don't want to change anything that may be in the string between the tags. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

[That does not happen for me](http://codepad.org/BHnIMXJa) (and it shouldn't).

It may be a space output somewhere else (use `var_dump()` to view the string).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I wish it was that simple but I tried trim() and it not only trimmed the space at the beginning of the string but all other spaces in the string. I just want that first space trimmed and no other spaces.

Comment: @David `trim()` only strips trailing and leaving whitespace.

Comment: Alex you were right I tried my code on a clean page with no css and so on and the beginning space is missing so I am picking up that space from somewhere else. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into this thread to see if you want to switch to using DOMDocument. It'll save you a great deal of headaches trying to parse through HTML.

[Robust and Mature HTML Parser for PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292926/robust-mature-html-parser-for-php)

Answer (score 0):

test:

```
<?php
$str = '<p class="code">some string here</p>';

$pattern = array();
$pattern[0] = '!<p class="code">!';
$pattern[1] = '!</p>!';
$result = preg_replace($pattern,"", $str);
var_dump($result);
```

result:

```
php pregrep.php                                                                  
string(16) "some string here"
```

seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Alex I figured out where I was picking up the extra space.

I was putting that code into a text area like this:

```
$str = '<p class="code">some string here</p>';
$pattern = array();
$pattern[0] = '!<p class="code">!';
$pattern[1] = '!</p>!';
$strip_str = preg_replace($pattern,"", $str);


<textarea id="code_area" class="syntaxhl" name="code" cols="66" rows="5">
 <?php echo $strip_str; ?>
</textarea>
```

This gave me my extra space but when I changed the code to:

```
<textarea id="code_area" class="syntaxhl" name="code" cols="66" rows="5"><?php echo $strip_str; ?></textarea>
```

No line spaces or breaks the extra space went away.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `trim()`?

```
$text = trim($text);
```

This removes white spaces around strings.